# Ternary Comparison Operator in Stata?

Tags: logic, comparison-operators, stata

In my Stata `do` scripts, I often have to compare dates which may be missing. Unfortunately, the internal representation of `.` is the largest possible number of the given range, so the following holds:

```
5 < .
```

This can become quite annoying e.g. when checking whether a date is within a certain range:

```
gen between_start_stop     = . if d == .
replace between_start_stop = 1 if ///
    !missing(d) & !missing(start) & !missing(stop) & ///
    start < d & d < stop
replace between_start_stop = 0 if ///
    ((!missing(d) & !missing(start) & !(start < d)) | ///
     (!missing(d) & !missing(stop) & !(d < stop))
```

instead of the following:

```
gen between_start_stop = (start < d) & (d < stop)
```

Is there a way to use **comparison operators** that work **with ternary logic**?

I.e., I would like the following statements to be true:

```
(5 < .) == .
(. < .) == .
(. < 5) == .
(. & 1) == .
(. & 0) == 0
etc...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of suggestions:

1. use `inrange()` (also look at inlist) to specify ranges instead of a series of `<` and `>` statements;
2. you can specify multiple items in `missing()` or `!missing()` statements like `!missing(start, stop, d)` and
3. it really sounds like you want to use `cond()`, which (using an ex from the help file) can be used to specify multiple conditions in one function:

   g var = 1 if cond(missing(x), ., cond(x>2,50,70))

returns `.` if `x` is missing, returns `50` if `x > 2`, and returns `70` if `x < 2`

Comment: Thanks eric, this is a huge improvement over my cluttered version. I edited your answer to format it and removed the signature since these are discouraged on StackOverflow. I hope you don't mind!

Answer (score 0):

The analogy does not get you what you want -- This formulation returns ‘missing’  when a known  d is below a known start (even if stop is, here irrelevantly, missing) or a known d is above a known stop (even if start is, here irrelevantly, missing).  The correct value in both cases is ‘false’.  I have a utility ('validly') which allows 'generate' to access three-valued logic and does what you want -- see discussion on my webpage http://www.nuffield.ox.ac.uk/People/sites/KIM/SitePages/Biography.aspx
which has a link to a paper expanding further (but be warned -- that has just been rejected by the Stata Journal as being "far too difficult to understand"